# Can Group of affine transformations generate CWT?

Tags: fourier-analysis, linear-transformations, harmonic-analysis, wavelets, linear-groups

I know group of translations in momentum space generate fourier transform.
Because in fourier transform we decompose a function as a sum different frequency components

$e^{ikx} $

What group of translations on momentum space do is

$U (k) e^{ifx} = e^{i(f-k)x} $

As this k runs over all its group elements through integration we get fourier transform from a fixed fiducial vector in momentum space.

What I need to know is, Can affine transformations in position or momentum space generate continues Wavelet transform?